# Analyzing output of a digital circuit with MUX

Tags: boolean-logic, boolean-expression, digital-logic

I have this circuit:

[image]

I need to:

1. find the output z
2. make it a canonical SOP
3. writing the minimal POS
4. finally expressing z with only NAND ports.

I'd like to receive suggestion(tricks?)/correction on my attempt as I am not 100% sure about it.

**Z output**

Okay I have some doubts regard the second operand of z, the output of the MUX. Since a MUX it's just a OR of NANDs between input and control lines (here x1/x2) I skipped the 0s and come out with just x3* ~x1x2 ( since it's the position 01) and ~x3*x1x2. Is my logic right here?

`z=x1x3+(~x1(x3 xor x2)) + (x3~x1x2+x1x2~x3)`

**Z as Canonical SOP**

I just elaborated z (done the xor and multiplication):

`z= x1x3+[~x1x2~x3+~x1~x2x3+~x1x2x3+x1x2~x3] = x1x2x3 + x1~x2x3 +[~x1x2~x3+~x1~x2x3+~x1x2x3+x1x2~x3]`

**Z as minimal POS**

Once I had the canonical POS I just built the truth table, the only 0 where at 000/001 (~x3~x2~x1 / ~x3~x2x1) then I used a k-map and the **minimal pos** resulted: `z=(x3+x2)`

**Expressing the whole thing with NANDs**

I just started from the POS expression:

`z = x3+x2 = NAND(~x3,~x2) = NAND(NAND(x3,x3),NAND(x2,x2))`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I tackled your question using `Logic Friday 1`:

[image]

Resulting equations:

Entered by gate diagram:

```
Z = X1' X3' X2 + X1' X3 X2' + X1 X3' X2 + X1 X3 X2' + X1 X3 X2;
```

Minimized:

```
Z = X3' X2 + X3 X2' + X1 X2;
```

I share your doubts about the multiplexer. Depending on the numbering of the data inputs (0..3 or 3..0) and selection inputs (0..1 or 1..0), you arrive at different results.

---

To check my results, I wrote a truth-table using the signal numbers of my circuit diagram:

[image]

This confirmed the five minterms.

Using a Karnaugh map:

```
             x2x3
       00  01  11  10
      +---+---+---+---+
   0  | 0 | 1 | 0 | 1 |
x1    +---+---+---+---+
   1  | 0 | 1 | 1 | 1 |
      +---+---+---+---+
```

This leads to product-of-sums POS:

```
(x2+x3) & (x1+!x2+!x3)
```

and sum-of-products SOP:

```
x2!x3 + !x2x3 + x1x2
```

The SOP can be written as:

```
NAND(NAND(x2, !x3), NAND(!x2, x3), NAND(x1, x2))
```

Comment: Our Z differs by one minterm that you miss while I don't: x3x2x1' which I get from the output of the multiplexer (second line: x1'x2x3). Now even if you chose a different numbering for the input, anyway you should have two minterms out of the MUX which would make six minterms (4 are from the other input in the final Z OR); so I think you maybe missed it while writing or you are wrong. Your minimized Z it's in SOP form which I didn't asked for, but I get a different result's there as well: x2+x3x2'

Comment: I saw your edit, your logic it's right and I would end with your same results BUT I think the difference it's in the MUX: my control lines are x1x2 and assuming 0..3 order (and skipping 0) I have: x3x1'x2 + x3'x1x2. We both have the last one but not x3x1'x2 this - seems to me- it's because your MUX control lines are x2x1. So basically I think your circuit it's different from mine. Anyway thanks for your efforts and, matter of fact, showing that my methodology it's right.